# Uniform convergence and integration: $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{n}} dx=?$

Tags: real-analysis, integration, uniform-convergence

For f$_n$(x)=$\frac{1}{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{n}}$, we need to calculate $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx$ . 
I want to prove f$_n$ is Riemann integrable and f$_n$ uniformly converges to f, then I can have $\lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx$  = $\int_{0}^{1} f(x)dx$.
But how to prove these two steps?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That $\int_0^1 f_n(x)\mathsf dx$ exists follows from $f_n$ being continuous and bounded on $[0,1]$. It's clear that the limit function is $f(x)=\frac1{1+x^2}$. To show that $f_n$ converges uniformly, it suffices to show that 
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x)-f_n(x)|\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0.$$
We compute
$$|f(x)-f_n(x)| = \left|\frac1{1+x^2}-\frac1{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}n} \right| = \frac{x^4}{n(1+x^2)\left(1+x^2 + \frac{x^4}n\right)}$$
(the absolute value isn't necessary since $f(x)>f_n(x)$ for all $n,x$). Since $0\leqslant x^4\leqslant 1$ and $(1+x^2)\left(1+x^2 + \frac{x^4}n\right)>1$ for all $n,x$, we have
$$\sup_{x\in[0,1]}|f(x) - f_n(x)|\leqslant\frac1n\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow 0.$$
Therefore 
\begin{align}
\lim_{n\to\infty}\int_0^1 f_n(x)\mathsf dx &= \int_0^1 f(x)\mathsf dx\\
&= \int_0^1 \frac1{1+x^2}\mathsf dx\\ &= \arctan 1 - \arctan 0\\ &= \frac\pi4.
\end{align}

As a side note, you don't actually need uniform convergence here. It's enough to observe that each $f_n$ has finite integral, $f_n(x)\stackrel{n\to\infty}\longrightarrow f(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$, and $f_n(x)<f_{n+1}(x)$ for all $x\in[0,1]$. Then we may interchange the limit and integral by the monotone convergence theorem.

Comment: Can I say since fn is monotonically on [0,1], then it is riemann integrable?

Comment: Yes; a  monotone function is a.e., differentiable so (at least) a.e. continuous.

Answer (score 1):

Hint:

Riemann integrabillity:

$$f_n(x) \text{   is continuous and bounded for all   } n$$

Uniform convergence:

$$|f_n(x) - f(x)| = \frac{1}{n}\frac{x^4}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2+x^4/n)} \leq \frac{1}{n},~~~~~{\rm for}~~~~x\in[0,1]$$

Answer (score 1):

You may just observe that, for each $x \in [0,1]$, we have
$$
f_n(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{n}} \to f(x)=\frac{1}{1+x^2}.
$$ But
$$
\begin{align}
\left|f(x)-f_n(x)\right|&=\left|\frac{1}{1+x^2}-\frac{1}{1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{n}}\right|\\\\
&=\left|\frac{\frac{x^4}{n}}{(1+x^2)(1+x^2+\frac{x^4}{n})}\right|\\\\
&\leq\left|\frac{\frac{1}{n}}{(1+0^2)(1+0^2+\frac{0^4}{n})}\right|\\\\
&\leq\frac{1}{n}\\\\
\end{align}
$$ and **the convergence is uniform** on $[0,1]$. You can deduce that

> $$
> \lim_{n \to \infty} \int_{0}^{1} f_n(x) dx=\int_{0}^{1} \frac{1}{1+x^2} dx=\color{red}{\frac{\pi}4}.
> $$